# Notes not getting saved due to html characters

Tags: javascript, notes

I am trying to escape all html characters with this function :

`strNotes.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/'/g,'&apos;').replace(/"/g,'&quot;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');`

But it seems like characters like  `&amp;` and `&gt;` gets converted in some hex decimal format when uploaded in static resource. 
In chrome debug it is shown as  `strNotes.replace(/&/g,"&#38;").replace(/'/g,"&#39;").replace(/"/g,"&#34;").replace(/</g,"&#60;").replace(/>/g,"&#62;").replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');`

Now when we try to save case, we are not able to save it because it converts html characters wrongly. has anyone faced this issue till now?

Salesforce wants `<` or '>' to get saved in `&gt;` or `&lt;`, but not sure why javascript changes that to hexdecimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone faces this issue in future, here is a library which handles all scenario:

https://github.com/WebReflection/html-escaper

Import this and every thing works fine.
Usage : `html.escape(strNotesEx)` or `html.unescape(strNotesEx)`